# Sending two commands over ssh in one subprocess.Popen list

Tags: python, ssh, command

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import sys

HOST=raw_input("\nInsert server(ex: xxXX.city):\n\n")
IP=raw_input("\nInsert ip:\n\n")
print ''
COMMAND='show arp hostname %s' % IP
COMMAND2='show route table inet.0 %s' % IP
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND, COMMAND2],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == 'xxx':
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print ''.join(result)
```

***I get this error***:

error: syntax error: show

***I'm guessing there is a problem with two commands chained in a subprocess.Popen. I say this because it looks like it executes each one with no problem. It's only when I put them chained that I get the error. I looked it up but I haven't found something clear about making two commands in one go with Popen..is there a way to make them work like the above but with a little twist or do I have to change the subprocess? thank you***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***with help from a friend the problem got solved like this:***

```
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, ';'.join([COMMAND, COMMAND2])],
```